# Display json data in a reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm new to react and fetch data api. I dont know how to display json data in one of my component. I have use axios to get data from api and this is my return json data

```json
{
  "result": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "excerpt": "egghead is your source for the Badass Portfolio Projects you need to climb the career ladder as a modern web developer.",
      "_id": 360690368,
      "title": "Build the portfolio you need to be a badass web developer.",
      "link": "https://egghead.io/",
      "domain": "egghead.io"
    },
    {
      "excerpt": "From career choices to new purchases, use René Girard’s mimetic theory to resist the herd and forge your own path in life",
      "_id": 359605780,
      "link": "https://psyche.co/guides/how-to-know-what-you-really-want-and-be-free-from-mimetic-desire?ref=refind",
      "title": "How to know what you really want | Psyche Guides",
      "domain": "psyche.co"
    }
  ],
  "count": 2,
  "collectionId": 0
}
```

**Here is list component:**

```
import * as React from "react"
import axios from "axios"

axios.get("https://api.abc.com", {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
})
.then(res => {
  const bookmarks = JSON.stringify(res.data)
  console.log(bookmarks)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})

const IndexPage = ({ bookmarks }) => (
  <>
    <h1>Show Data</h1>
    <div>
      {bookmarks.items.map(bookmark => (
        <div>{bookmark.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Can anyone help me in displaying the list? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way how data fetching in react works... you must fetch your data in components `useEffect` and store your data in `useState` hook, which will cause rerender and you can access this data:

```
import * as React from "react"
import axios from "axios"



const IndexPage = () => (
const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = React.useState()

React.useEffect(()=>{
axios.get("https://api.abc.com", {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
})
.then(res => {
  const bookmarks = JSON.stringify(res.data)
  setBookmarks(bookmarks)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
},[])
return(
  <>
    <h1>Show Data</h1>
    <div>
      {bookmarks.items.map(bookmark => (
        <div>{bookmark.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </>
)
```

---

edit: with custom loading solution:

```
import * as React from "react"
import axios from "axios"


const IndexPage = () => (
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = React.useState()

React.useEffect(()=>{
axios.get("https://api.abc.com", {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
})
.then(res => {
  const bookmarks = JSON.stringify(res.data)
  setBookmarks(bookmarks)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
}).finally(()=>{setLoading(false)});
},[])

if(loading){
 return (<>Loading...</>)
}

return(
  <>
    <h1>Show Data</h1>
    <div>
      {bookmarks.items.map(bookmark => (
        <div>{bookmark.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Hi @Wraithy first of all thank you for helping me. I have corrected the above code but when I run it, the error is like this

Comment: you need there to check if bookmarks.items exists: `{bookmarks && bookmarks.items && items && bookmakrs.items.map(...` or you can use optional chaining `{bookmarks?.items?.map(...`

Comment: Or you can made some custom implementation of some kind of loader